# Understanding the class declaration in C++

Tags: c++, arduino

Trying to develop an understanding of the functioning of the the [SDFat](https://github.com/greiman/SdFat) library for Arduino IDE. I stumbled across these lines of codes in the SDfat.h header file.

```
/**
 1* \class SdBaseFile
 2* \brief Class for backward compatibility.
 3*/
 4 class SdBaseFile : public FatFile {
 5 public:
 6 SdBaseFile() {}
 7 /**  Create a file object and open it in the current working directory.
 8  *
 9  * \param[in] path A path for a file to be opened.
 10  *
 11 * \param[in] oflag Values for \a oflag are constructed by a
 12  * bitwise-inclusive OR of open flags. see
 13  * FatFile::open(FatFile*, const char*, uint8_t).
 14  */
 15 SdBaseFile(const char* path, uint8_t oflag) : FatFile(path, oflag) {}
 16 };
```

If someone could please explain me how this class declaration works.

1) What does the `:public Fatfile` in line#4 do.

2) Why are there two constructors in line#6 and line#15 (if at all they are that).

My comprehension is being limited by the lack of syntactical understanding of the definition/ declaration here. Appreciate the help.

Thanks

Comment: 1. It means that this class is derived from another class named FatFile. 2. The class can be instantiated in two ways, so there's two constructors. I suggest that you read a good book on C++

Comment: Any C++ tutorial/book would answer these questions in detail. 1) Inheritance. 2) Yes, they are constructors, the first is a default constructor, the other is a constructor that takes input to open a file

Comment: Read up on inheritance and function overloading. For book recommendations, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `:public Fatfile` means that `SdBaseFile` publically inherits from `Fatfile`.
   This is actually called an `is-a` relationship i.e `SdBaseFile` is-a `Fatfile`. You can use a `Fatfile *` to point to objects of `SdBaseFile`.
2. There are two type of constructors, one does not take any arguments, and the other one takes two arguments, those two arguments are in fact passed to the base class from which this class `SdBaseFile` has been derived.

Answer (score 2):

1. `:public Fatfile` means that the class `SdBaseFile` inherits from the class `FatFile`
2. A class may have multiple constructors (this is not only C++, but most object-oriented languages, as far as I know). When you use the class `SdBaseFile` you can choose any of these constructors.

Answer (score 1):

keep in mind the 'SdBaseFile() {}' is the default constructor.  This is always defined in a class and usually when a framework doesn't want the default constructor called it will be a private constructor.

the other constructor seems to be what you want to used.  As the default constructor doesn't seem to do anything other than construct an class with no file associated with it.  My impression of this would change if I knew what was in the FatFile class.

Comment: The default constructor is not always defined: when omitted, the compiler will only provide a default constructor for you if you do not define any other constructors.